# Can domain classes be configured to insert a new record instead of updating when saved?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

When I change a domain object, rather than updating the database record, I'd like to archive the old record record and create a new one.  I'd like to force GORM to do this automatically.

For example, if I had this domain class:

```
class User {
    String username
    String email
    Boolean active
}
```

then I'd like

```
user.email = email
user.save()
```

to set the active flag on the user to false, keeping a record of the old email.  A new record with the new email address and active = true would be inserted.

Is this a common pattern?  Is it easy to do in the domain class so that it happens transparently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GORM event `beforeUpdate` into User domain class  (see the documentation  [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) and [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.3.6%20Modification%20Checking)) with something like the following should work (not tested) :

```
def beforeUpdate() {
  if (isDirty('email') { //enters only if email was changed. Works only with Grails 1.3.x
  User.withNewSession {
    //Create the new entry
    new User(username:username, email:email).save()
    //Update the old entry with the old email value
    email = getPersistentValue('email')
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about that. But how do you get the new inserted user (to replace your old instance)?

Comment: If i create the new User in a new Session, it will be in another transaction, won't it?  Ideally, I'd like it to rollback with the rest of the transaction if something fails.

Comment: @ataylor yes it is another transaction. Just check the return valuse of save() and propagates the error to the other transaction for rolling back
@Pascal The only way I have in mind now is : User.findByEmail(new_email), or storing the new user ID in a scope like session or flash

Answer (score 2):

One option I can think of would be to implement a [soft delete](http://featurenotbug.com/2009/07/soft-deletes-using-hibernate-annotations/) and then persist a new user. I realize this is not exactly what you're asking for but I don't know how to do this with a single save. Not ideal IMO.

Another (probably better) approach would be to use [Hibernate Envers](http://jboss.org/envers) to "version" the `User` entity and keep an history of changes. I don't know the exact status of Envers with Grails but it looks like there is a [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/grails-envers-plugin/) for it. See also [[grails-user] GORM & Envers / Audit History Tables](http://www.pubbs.net/200912/grails/12916-grails-user-gorm-amp-envers-audit-history-tables.html).

Comment: This is also a good global solution. Have you ever tried Envers with Grails ?

Comment: @fabien7474: No, never. I honestly don't know what the current status of Envers with Grails is (I don't really do Grails actually).